# Timestamp for 1st day of year

Tags: javascript

I am doing the following:

new Date().setFullYear(2011, 0, 1);

Does this gives me the number of seconds since January 1, 1970?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, Javascript stores a date as the number of milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970. (Not seconds -- milliseconds.) You can get this number out of the date object with the getTime function.

In practice, the "base date" rarely makes a difference. Usually you use the various Date functions to format the date in a conventional format. You occasionally get differences between two times by using getTime and subtracting one from another.

Answer (score 1):

```
> new Date().setFullYear(2011, 0, 1);
```

> Does this gives me the number of seconds since January 1, 1970?

No, because the hours, minutes and seconds need to be zeroed too:

```
x = new Date();
x.setFullYear(2011, 0, 1);
x.setHours(0, 0, 0);

alert(x - 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

That just gives you a date object.

```
Date d = new Date().setFullYear(2011, 0, 1);
d.getSeconds(); //gives you number of seconds for the date you've set (0-59), but not from Jan 1,1970.
```

Comment: -1 - it gives the number of seconds *from the epoch*, which is 1/1/1970. Read ES5 §15.9.1.1 `Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC`.

Comment: You're wrong. d.getSeconds() does not do that. It returns the number of seconds (0-59) of the current time. I know that time is mesured internally that way, but that function does not give you the number of seconds from epoch. http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html

Comment: Umm, maybe the original post has been edited, but it makes no reference to the getSeconds function, so I'm not sure why you're debating that.